# replaceRoute not working as expected?

Tags: ember.js

I recently wanted some routes in my emberjs app not to show up in the browser history and tried to leverage the replaceRoute functionality that was introduced in the RC1. Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference at all if I use transitionToRoute or replaceRoute.
Let's say I have 3 pages and I want page 1 to be skipped when going back in history.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {goBack:function(){window.history.back();}}
});

App.Page1Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  goToPage2: function(){
    this.replaceRoute("page2")
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("page1");
  this.route("page2");
  this.route("page3");
});
```

I've made a little JSFiddle example for testing http://jsfiddle.net/ripcurlx/Qmnrj/3/

Am I using the replaceRoute completely wrong, or is there a better solution to prevent certain routes not to be included in the browser history?
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: It looks like this only works if you use location:"history" instead of location:"hash". I'll have a look if I'm able to implement it somehow for the Ember.HashLocation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this only works with `location: "history"`. Browsers have no support for updating the hash without affecting history, whereas when using history states, there is the provided `replaceState` method which we can utilize.

Comment: Thanks anyways! After reading through the implementation of the History and HashLocation I thought about extending this functionality by jumping back in history and setting the hash url afterwards. But somehow it always resulted in some flickering on mobile. Anyways I ended up in implementing a custom history controller to handle the back button behavior within the app.